# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was string at path $[0]

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

[JSON](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Maximsiomin/DomainsAPI/master/domains_list.json)

I try to parse JSON from the link. Here's my code

```
private const val BASE_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/"

private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(RetrofitUtil.BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface DomainsApiService {
    @GET("Maximsiomin/DomainsAPI/master/domains_list.json")
    fun getAllDomains(): Call<List<Domain>>
}

object DomainsAPI {
    val retrofitService: DomainsApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(DomainsApiService::class.java) }
}

data class Domain(
    @Json(name = JSON.DOMAIN) val domain: String
)
```

Here i process JSON:

```
fun getDomainsList(domain: String, context: Context) {
    DomainsAPI.retrofitService.getAllDomains().enqueue( object: Callback<List<Domain>> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Domain>>, t: Throwable) {
            Timber.d("onFailure called")
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Domain>>, response: Response<List<Domain>>) {
            Timber.d("onResponse called")
            _response.value = response.body()?.size.toString()
        }
    })
}
```

But I have Toast with error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was string at path $[0]". I tried to edit json file and made a dict, but got same error. What can I do?

Comment: Your data is an array of strings, not an array of `Domain` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API is returning Array of Strings, but you are fetching array of Domain Objects.

[image]

Change:

```
  Call<List<Domain>>
```

to

```
  Call<List<String>>
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
fun getAllDomains(): Call<List<Domain>>
```

to

```
fun getAllDomains(): Call<List<String>>
```

because api return list of strings not objects https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlUEB.jpg